# What does points of odd order mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't really understands odd order in a point context?

An example:

> Let $K$ be a field of odd characteristic. Let $E_{E,a,d}$ be a twisted
>   Edwards curve defined over $K$. Let $P = (x_1, y_1)$ and $Q = (x_2,
> > y_2)$ be points on $E_{E,a,d}$. Assume that P and Q are of **odd
>   order??**. It follows that $1−dx_1x_2y_1y_2 \neq 0$ and $1
> > +dx_1x_2y_1y_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Yesterday you asked "what is a field of odd characteristic?".  Do you mean to ask about "odd integers" in general,  or about "order" and "characteristic"? The idea of parity (even vs. odd) applies to *all* objects that are integers (and even more generally to fractions with odd denominators).

Comment: I think it became a question of "odd integers" at the end. I just couldn't make that connection at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a group structure on [an elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law), which [twisted Edwards curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve#Edwards_addition_law) are examples of. The order of an element $P$ is then the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $P^k$ (in the sense of the group's multiplication) is the identity element.

Comment: And I guess if k is odd. It is of odd order?

Comment: @einstein precisely.